# spaces not getting printed in html

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a django html template which has this form in it

```
<form action="/image_info/" method="POST" id='image_form'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="imginfo" name='info_button' value={{x.desc}} type="submit">info</button>
</form>
```

The above form will POST the `value` to `views.py` whenever the submit button is pressed. but the problem is `{{x.desc}}` is a sentence and has blank spaces in it so only the first word is getting posted. I need the whole sentence. How should I do it. here `x` is a model and `desc` is its object.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add quotes to your `value` attribute

```
  <button class="imginfo" name='info_button' value="{{x.desc}}" type="submit">info</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/image_info/" method="POST" id='image_form'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ x.desc }}">
  <button class="imginfo" name='info_button' type="submit">info</button>
</form>
```

use hidden input